# Copy files from windows server from Linux server using python script

Tags: ssh, scp

1) Can anyone please suggest me a way to copy files from windows server to linux server?

2) Initially I couldn't connect my windows server in linux server by using below command.

In Linux terminal, 
ssh

I'm getting connection refused error.

Kindly anyone suggest me solution for above 2 questions.

Comment: First, you need to be able to download the files using any existing GUI/command-line client. If you are not able to do that, there's no point trying to implement the same using any language. You do not have a programming question. Start by asking a generic question on file transfer on [su].

Answer (score 0):

Normally windows does not run an ssh daemon (server). Therefore you normally cannot connect from linux to windows unless you set one up on windows.

The reverse is different. Linux normally runs an ssh daemon, so you can connect to it from windows *provided* you install a suitable client (e.g. putty).

**However**, in both cases, port 22 (the ssh port) will likely be blocked for incoming connections. You will need to open this port on the "server side". For details as to how this, you would need to search for your particular operating system. B.T.W. You will alost certainly need administrator priviliges to open network ports. For example, if you use putty (or similar) on windows, you will need to ensure that port 22 is open on the Linux system.

Once you have openned port 22, you can use scp (or pscp if you download putty tools to windows) to copy files over the network. Another popular tool is WinSCP which allows you to copy files from windows to linux using a file explorer type of interface (e.g. you can drag and drop them).

Having said all of that, it might be easier to just copy everything to a USB drive, then plug the USB drive into the other system and copy the files off of it. This of course assumes you have physical access to both systems.

Comment: Can you please suggest me a way to copy files from windows server to linux server using python script? Also windows server to another windows server.

Comment: You first need to be able to resolve the connection refused problem. If you do not resolve that problem, you will not be able to transfer your files - no matter what tool you use. Once you have solved the connection refused problem, post a **new** question about how to do an scp in python. Make sure you make an attempt to write the python version by yourself first as you probably will not get a favourable response if you do not at least make an attempt and post an example showing the code that you have tried so far.

Comment: Oh, and if you resolve the connection refused question and this post helped you, please accept it as the answer. You will receive reputation points when you do.